# Insert values into table from csv file using psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to insert values into table from my csv file.
I write this code:

```
conn = ps.connect(
                        host="#######",
                        database="#####",
                        user="######",
                        port="#####",
                        password="######")

cur = conn.cursor()

with open('C:\\Users\\maciej.olech\\Desktop\\structure_files\\MAG.csv', 'r') as f:
     
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'mag', sep=',')

conn.commit()
```

This work fine when I insert files that dont have empty spaces.
When I try to load a file which contains empty fields i get this error:

`InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: "" CONTEXT:  COPY mag, line 456193, column kdur: ""`

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Clean up the CSV file so `..some_data, "', other_data...`  becomes `..some_data, , other_data...` where the unquoted empty string will be entered as `NULL`. 2) Import the CSV data into a staging table where all the fields are `varchar` and then do the clean up there or when transferring from staging table to final table.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Thanks I clear files from nan values and now insert work correctly.